# Cannot change vertical Y label color in Android AChartEngine and configure margins

Tags: android, achartengine

I have tried to edit [the sample project](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-1.1.0-demo-source.zip&can=2&q=) of AChartEngine library.

For the X orizontal axis with

```
myrender.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
```

I can change the labels color

The command

```
 myrender.setYLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
```

doesn't exist, there is
 myrender.setYLabelsColor(int scale, int color);

that I haven't understood how to use and if I try something like

```
myrender.setYLabelsColor(1, Color.BLACK);
```

crashes

How should I change the Y labels colors and configure margins in the circled sections?

[image]

Comment: What error get when you use `setYLabelsColor`?

Comment: get an indexOutOfBoundException

Comment: ok, give a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to change Y labels colors

```
myrender.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
```

To change the margins you have to use

```
setMargins(int yourmargins[]);
```

the `yourmargins` array must contain your margins values in pixel in the order top, left, bottom, right